# calendario tkinter python no imprime nada

Tags: python, tkinter

efectivamente ayer el codigo que colgué estaba mal indentado pero fue al copiar aquí... el mío estaba correcto. Sigo intentando imprimir un calendario pero no me imprime un carajo. Me podéis echarían mano a encontrar donde la estoy liando?? APUNTO QUE SOY SUPER NOVATA.

```
import calendar
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import datetime

year = datetime.date.today().year
month = datetime.date.today().month


class calendar(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **arg):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, height = 532, width = 422)
        self.pack_propagate(0)

        self.init_frames()
        self.mesAnterior
        self.mesSiguiente()
        self.añoAnterior()
        self.añoSiguiente()
        self.writeCalendar()

        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="", font=('arial', 28, 'bold'), bg='white', justify=LEFT)
        label1.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.ttk.Button_anteriorM(frame,text="<", width=5, command=mesAnterior)
        self.ttk.Button_anteriorM.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.ttk.Button_siguienteM(frame,text=">", width=5, command=mesSiguiente)
        self.ttk.Button_siguienteM.grid(row = 0, column = 5)

        self.ttk.Button_siguienteA(frame,text=">>", width=5, command=añoSiguiente)
        self.ttk.Button_siguienteA.grid(row = 0, column = 6)

        self.ttk.Button_anteriorA(frame,text="<<", width=5, command=añoAnterior)
        self.ttk.Button_anteriorA.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    def init_frames(self):
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.frame_days = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_days.pack()

    def writeCalendar(year,month):
        label1.configure(text=calendar.month(year, month))

    def mesAnterior():
        global month,year
        month-=1
        if month==0:
            month=12
            year-=1

        writeCalendar(year,month)

    def mesSiguiente():
        global month,year
        month+=1
        if month==13:
            month=1
            year+=1

        writeCalendar(year,month)

    def añoSiguiente():
        global month, year
        year += 1
        if year == year + 1:
            year = year
            month = month + 12
        writeCalendar(year,month)

    def añoAnterior():
        global month, year
        year -= 1
        if year == year - 1:
            year = year
            month = month - 12

        writeCalendar(year,month)


class MainApp(Tk):
    __displayCalendario = None

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Calendario")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.__displayCalendario = calendar(self)
        self.__displayCalendario.place(x = 0, y = 1)

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar

```
filas_calendario = calendar.month(year, month).splitlines()
```

deja en **filas_calendario**, una lista en donde cada registro corresponde a una fila del calendario; Una fila para el año y mes, una para los nombres de los días, y una para cada semana.

Luego recorro cada fila y discrimino si se trara de la que contiene el nombre del mes y el año, del resto.

```
for numero_de_fila, fila in enumerate(filas_calendario):
```

Si es la primera fila, entonces la centro y le agrego un salto de línea al final. Si no es así, se invoca la función **repartirAnchoCaracteres**, 
que recibe una cadena de caracteres que corresponde a una fila del calendario. Dentro de la función, el comportamiento es el siguiente.

```
    for indice in range(0, len(cadena), 3):
```

Recorre la cadena recibida de tres en tres, esto porque así es el formato que entregó inicialmente el módulo **calendar**. Luego,

```
trozo = cadena[indice:indice+3]
```

guarda en *trozo*, el "recorte" de la cadena principal, que corresponderá a un nombre o número de día. Con

```
largo_util = len(trozo.strip())
```

se obtiene el largo del nombre o número de día, pero sin quitando los espacios. Dependiendo de la variable **largo_util**, se concatenan distintas cantidades del caracter *espacio*,
en caso de que la variable **trozo** no sea un número, es decir, que corresponda a un nombre de día, se pasa a mínusculas, para normalizar un poco, su ancho.

En resumen, la función **repartirAnchoCaracteres** lee los valores de una fila del calendario, y la retorna con los caracteres rellenados dependiendo de su ancho.

Después de esto, fuera de la función, se le agrega un salto de línea al final de la cadena, y se concatena este resultado en la variable **calendario_ajustado**,
que es la que finalmente se muestra en la etiqueta "label1".

```
import calendar
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import datetime
from re import sub

year = datetime.date.today().year
month = datetime.date.today().month


class Calendario(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **arg):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, height = 532, width = 422)
        self.pack_propagate(0)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="", font=('arial', 28, 'bold'), justify=LEFT)
        self.label1.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=7)

        self.boton_anteriorM = ttk.Button(self, text="<", width=5, command=self.mesAnterior)
        self.boton_anteriorM.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.boton_siguienteM = ttk.Button(self,text=">", width=5, command=self.mesSiguiente)
        self.boton_siguienteM.grid(row = 0, column = 5)

        self.boton_siguienteA = ttk.Button(self,text=">>", width=5, command=self.añoSiguiente)
        self.boton_siguienteA.grid(row = 0, column = 6)

        self.boton_anteriorA = ttk.Button(self,text="<<", width=5, command=self.añoAnterior)
        self.boton_anteriorA.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.writeCalendar(year, month)

    def repartirAnchoCaracteres(self, cadena):
        salida = ""
        for indice in range(0, len(cadena), 3):
            trozo = cadena[indice:indice+3]
            largo_util = len(trozo.strip())
            if largo_util == 0:
                salida += "     "
            elif largo_util == 1:
                salida += "   " + trozo.strip()
            else:
                if trozo.strip().isdigit() is False:
                    trozo = trozo.lower()
                salida += " " + trozo.strip()
        return salida

    def writeCalendar(self, year, month):
        filas_calendario = calendar.month(year, month).splitlines()
        calendario_ajustado = ""

        for numero_de_fila, fila in enumerate(filas_calendario):
            if numero_de_fila < 1:
                calendario_ajustado += (fila.center(20, " ") + "\n")
            else:
                calendario_ajustado += self.repartirAnchoCaracteres(fila) + "\n"
        self.label1.configure(text=calendario_ajustado)

    def mesAnterior(self):
        global month,year
        month-=1
        if month==0:
            month=12
            year-=1

        self.writeCalendar(year,month)

    def mesSiguiente(self):
        global month,year
        month+=1
        if month==13:
            month=1
            year+=1

        self.writeCalendar(year,month)

    def añoSiguiente(self):
        global month, year
        year += 1
        if year == year + 1:
            year = year
            month = month + 12
        self.writeCalendar(year,month)

    def añoAnterior(self):
        global month, year
        year -= 1
        if year == year - 1:
            year = year
            month = month - 12

        self.writeCalendar(year,month)


class MainApp(Tk):
    __displayCalendario = None

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Calendario")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.geometry("380x380+100+100")
        self.__displayCalendario = Calendario(self)
        self.__displayCalendario.place(x = 0, y = 1)

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.start()
```

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, muchas gracias! Pero necesito que todo sea con -----ttk----. He corrido tu codigo para poder coger ideas y la verdad es que me salen las flechitas y tal pero nada parecido a un calendario.

Comment: Eva, una duda. El calendario sólo tiene que mostrarse, o esperas poder seleccionar fechas directamente presionando los días?

Comment: tiene que mostrarse el calendario nada mas y poder cambiar de año y mes por las flechas

Comment: Ya edité el código que puse como respuesta. Podrías validar que es eso lo que necesitas?

Comment: esta casi casi, lo único es que sale descolocadisimo que es parte de lo que me ocurría a mi también. Esto esta siendo tedioso

Comment: Cambia la fuente de **self.label1** de "arial" a "Consolas", ésta última es *mono espaciada*, lo que significa que todos los caracteres tienen el mismo ancho.

Comment: es requisito del programa que sea arial :(

Comment: Eva, actualicé nuevamente la respuesta, por favor, haz tus pruebas y me cuentas. Te explico los cambios en la respuesta actualizada. Teniendo en cuenta que es un requisito que el calendario tenga "arial", como fuente, y que ésta no es mono espaciada, es decir, que los caracteres tienen anchos diferentes, creé una función para ajustar el ancho, de cada número o espacio (ausencia de número).

Comment: mil gracias!! En estos dias colgare otro codigo con el que estoy liada. Es otro calendario pero esta vez cn un formato especifico tkinter. Es para hacer una calendario permanente con aspecto del típico de papel con festivos en rojo, y cuadrícula. Ahora estoy con la cuadricula pero no se muy bien si odre reutilizar el código de este ultimo que he conseguido ordenar gracias a ti.